# Unit test failing with Junit and Hamcrest - Not able to compare data with two List objects

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, hamcrest

I have the following test that is actually asserting the data within two Lists. But even though the data is same, the test does not pass. I googled and found SO links which pointed to using `assertThat(actual, containsInAnyOrder(expected.toArray()));` but no luck.

```
@Test
public void testGetOrderLines() {
    List<OrderLine> expResult = new ArrayList<>();
    OrderLine orderLine = new OrderLine(100, 5, "http://image-url.com", "Baby Gym",
            1, "physical", "http://product-url.com", 100, "pcs", "100-123");
    expResult.add(orderLine);
    List<OrderLine> result = instance.getOrderLines();
    assertThat(expResult, containsInAnyOrder(result.toArray()));
}
```

**Error:**

> Failed tests:
>         AuthorizationRequestTest.testGetOrderLines:92
>       Expected: iterable over [http://image-url.com,name=Baby Gym,quantity=1,type=physical,productUrl=http://product-url.com,unitPrice=100,quantityUnit=pcs,reference=100-123]>] in any order
>            but: Not matched: http://image-url.com,name=Baby Gym,quantity=1,type=physical,productUrl=http://product-url.com,unitPrice=100,quantityUnit=pcs,reference=100-123]>

Comment: I assume that `equals` is implemented sensibly?

Comment: @JoeC and `hashCode`, presumably.

Comment: No, hashCode and equals implementation is not there. Since the model class is under my control I can certainly go ahead and implement both the above methods but just wondering how would I go about testing this if this were a class from the 3rd party jar?

Comment: there you go then!

Comment: @Darshan - My second question still stands. How would you compare these two Lists if the class is defined in a 3rd party jar that we have control no control over?

Comment: Regarding matching with 3rd party classes - write your own matcher and use the following method:  http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#containsInAnyOrder(org.hamcrest.Matcher...) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no chance to implement an `equals()` method you may use a reflection based equality-assertion. e.g. [unitils](http://unitils.sourceforge.net/tutorial-reflectionassert.html). It also works on objects contained in lists or arrays. Be aware that if the order may differ, you must use the lenient order comparator mode. Here is an example:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.unitils.reflectionassert.ReflectionComparatorMode;
import static org.unitils.reflectionassert.ReflectionAssert.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ReflectionEqualsTest {

    public static class A {
        private String x;

        public A(String text) {
            this.x = text;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testCompareListsOfObjectsWithoutEqualsImplementation() throws Exception {
        List<A> list = Arrays.asList(new A("1"), new A("2"));
        List<A> equalList = Arrays.asList(new A("1"), new A("2"));
        List<A> listInDifferentOrder = Arrays.asList(new A("2"), new A("1"));

        assertNotEquals(list, equalList);
        assertNotEquals(list, listInDifferentOrder);

        assertReflectionEquals(list, equalList);
        assertReflectionEquals(list, listInDifferentOrder, 
                        ReflectionComparatorMode.LENIENT_ORDER);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice idea. Of course, comes at the usual "reflections" cost (as you really don't know what kind of fields such containers have, what exactly gets compared); but I wasnt aware of assertReflectionEquals(). Not something I would normally use, but for sure: when you need it, then using a library is better than implementing that assert yourself!